# I removed Ubuntu and Kali my windows 10 system but i still boot into grub (not rescue)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

So i see this question has been asked alot but my issue is that i deleted the Linux partitions of my 2nd hard drive and repaired the bootloader ran bootrec /fixmbr, fixboot.

I still boot into the grub cmdline( it does not say rescue anywhere). I feel like i haven't completely removed grub or it was installed  2 version and i only deleted one.

Also when i press f12 while booting the Ubuntu boot option is still there but there are no Linux partions left on my drives.

How to i completely get rid of grub ?

Comment: http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/ im trying this now i hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/ This fixed it for me. This issue is taken care of